# Pytest testing functions with file read (hardcoded file path)

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

Can't wrap my mind around how to test my function which search for files.
My current tree:

```
project
- etls
-- app.py
-- pipeline_1
---- pipeline_1.yaml
-- pipeline_2
---- pipeline_2.yaml
- tests
--  etl
--- unit
---- tests_appfile.py
- conftest.py
```

In my `tests_appfile.py` I would like to test function from `app.py`
The function is:

```py
def get_yaml_path(job_name: str) -> str:
    list_of_paths = list(Path("etls").rglob(f"{job_name}.yaml"))
    if len(list_of_paths) > 1:
        raise ValueError(
            f"Number of paths > 1 (actual value: {len(list_of_paths)}. Can't decide which pipeline to run"
        )
    elif len(list_of_paths) == 0:
        raise ValueError(f"There is no YAML files for that {job_name}")
    else:
        return str(list_of_paths[0])
```

So, I run `app.py` with param `job_name`, function have to find specific YAML for that job.
I want to test it and the main caveat here is that `'etls'` is hardcoded path here. My ideas are:

- to create fixture that creates fake folders and YAMLs for test
- change workdir to temd_dir from pytest during tests and create there `'etls'` folder and etc.

Which approach is more efficient considering I will need this YAMLS for another tests and how to implement them?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:
Created the fixture

```py
@pytest.fixture
def test_appfile_yaml_files(tmp_path):
    directory = tmp_path / "etls/test_pipeline"
    directory.mkdir(parents=True)
    file_path = directory / "test_pipeline.yaml"
    file_path.write_text("this is temp yaml file")
    return file_path
```

And then monkeypatch the working dir

```py
def test_get_yaml_path(test_appfile_yaml_files, tmp_path, monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.chdir(tmp_path)
    assert get_yaml_path("test_pipeline") == "etls/test_pipeline/test_pipeline.yaml"
```